# apache ProxyPassMatch .htaccess issue

Tags: lighttpd, apache

In a virtualhost environment, I have apache proxying static content to a lighttpd backend for performance, and also to bypass mod_security performance hits on static content using the following ProxyPassMatch statement:

ProxyPassMatch (? < ! \ .php|.pl|cgi|htm|html|shtml|/)$ http : // 127.0.0.1:35436/

(:35436 is my lighttpd port)

This setup works well to proxy anything that isn't any of the above to lighttpd. My issue is, as I've just uncovered, that Custom ErrorDocuments don't work very well.

The .htaccess is the simple: ErrorDocument 404 /404.htm

For example a 404 on foo.com/bar.htm works as it's handled by apache / .htaccess
foo.com/bar does not work, the 404 goes via lighttpd
foo.com/bar/ does work as it's handled by apache / .htaccess (assumed /index.*)

I know the syntax to add 404s to the lighttpd configuration but as it's a virtualhost environment I'd like the user to be able to control this via a single .htaccess file.

Is there any way to force apache to deal with 404s (and the other standard error pages) rather than obeying its own ProxyPassMatch statement?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
ProxyErrorOverride On
```

To use apache 404 response when a 404 header is in the response from lighthttpd.

Comment: thankyou for the reply. I've put it in but I don't think it's working. The ProxyPassMatch statement is a negative lookbehind so essentially apache is cherrypicking what it wants to serve and shoves everything else through the reverseproxy.  Lighttpd is acknowledging the 404 in its logs but not sending it back to apache.

Comment: Not sending back the response? you should get a 503 - bad gateway if this happen. Increase apache log level and track the proxy communication in it.

Comment: Apologies, either I didn't explain well or you misread my regex. It will always pass the file to lighttpd based on filetype and 'then' generate the 404. ProxyErrorMatch won't deal with this. What I did was tell lighttpd to proxy all .php back to apache, and set a global 404 server.error-handler-404 in the main lighttpd.conf to 404.php. This means that any 404 lighttpd receives will go to 404.php (which may or may not exist) and be reparsed via the proxy to apache which will then handle it as per the .htaccess. Bit hacky but there we go.

Comment: yes, bit hacky, with proxyerrorOverride you would just have to wait for the 404 response from lighthttpd, and rewrite it via the apache 404, so every 404 not handled by apache at first would be handled when lighthttpd returns a 404.